# Como registrar hora y fecha horaria en mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente estoy  registrando el ingreso de datos pero me registra una hora que no es la correcta.

```html
Mi metodo  para registrar ingreso por persona:

function insert_log($idcliente)
 {
  $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  $data = array(
   'fec_acc' =>$date,
   'idcliente' => $idcliente
   );
  $this->db->insert('access_cliente',$data);
  return;
 }
```

Comment: Y por que no dejarlo con un default de lado de la base de datos?

Comment: Hay forma de elergia la zona horaria al momento de inserta el registro de ingreso @edgar-vazquez

Comment: Si podrias intentar con esto SET GLOBAL time_zone = "America/Mexico_City";

Comment: Eso donde lo tengo que ejecutar ?

Comment: En tu base de datos, podrias usar un sp y pasar parametros y dentro del sp pones la sentencia que te puse

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenia el mismo problema y lo solucione de la siguiente forma.
Ya que el trabajo con fechas es algo que siempre se usa mucho pues me creen un archivo helper en el cual pongo las funciones que más ocupo como por ejemplo esta de la fecha, quedando de esta forma

```
function fecha($timestamp){
  $date = new DateTime();
  $date->setTimestamp($timestamp);
  return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

y en mi controlador pues lo llamo así ejemplo

```
$log = array(
         'fecha' => fecha(now('America/Mexico_City'))
        );
```